# Toggle Images on Click (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation button and I want to change the image everytime the user clicks on it (from the Menu icon to the Close icon), this is the code I'm currently using but when I swap the text to images the Close icon doesn't "go back" to the Menu icon for some reason.

Any help? Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mobileMenu').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').toggleClass('menuOpened');
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Close' ? 'Menu' : 'Close');
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="mobileMenuRight">
  <a href="/cart" class="mobileCart"><img src="../cartIcon.png" alt="Cart" height="22"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: add the html for the icon

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
$('.mobileMenuRight').click( function() {
  if (!$('.mobileMenuRight').hasClass('menuOpened')) {
    $('.mobileMenuRight').addClass('menuOpened');
    $('.mobileCart ' + 'img').attr({
      src: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/8888888",
    });
  } else {
    $('.mobileMenuRight').removeClass('menuOpened');
    $('.mobileCart ' + 'img').attr({
      src: "http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/8888888/000000",
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobileMenuRight">
  <a href="#" class="mobileCart"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/8888888/000000" alt="Cart" height="22"></a>
```

Comment: @chrisbedoya Did my answer help you, or did you ran into trouble?